# url rewriting in php on xampp server

Tags: url-rewriting

I've trying out url rewriting with a php script on my xampp server. First i created a .htaccess on the same folder as the script and then wrote the following lines in it

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteRule ^direct/?$ direct_name_here.php [NC,L]
```

to rewrite localhost/map/direct_here123.php to localhost/map/direct/

But the browser displays the url localhost/map/direct_here123.php instead of localhost/map/direct/

How can i fix it?

regards
ED